# "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" after deploy

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I've been trying to fix this issue for 2 days now and I couldn't find a viable solution yet :(

I am deploying my React Single-Page App onto Firebase Hosting but I get this famous page "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" after deploy.
I've tried to deploy from the index.html in the public and build folder but none of them works. It looks like I don't have a firebase.json nor a firebaserc file created in my project after init. Could it be the reason?

Here are screenshots of the setup :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftbtI.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I was actually running the command outside my project /users/maxime instead of /users/maxime/projectname !

Answer (score 0):

Update your index.html file on this code then command `npm run build` then `firebase deploy` it will be working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure project build done correctly.

Building when `firebase init` sometimes don't work correctly.

So run build command (eg: `npm run build`) mannualy before `firebase deploy`

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy with firebaseCLI after deploying it gives your ***Hosting URL*** ends with  ***.web.app*** . And it shows **Firebase Hosting Setup Completed**.

**Solution 1** -> Simply change the end of URL **".web.app"** to **".firebase.app"**

***Solution 2*** -> Go to dir **build/web/index.html**, in **firebaseConfig** and see **authDomain: "blablabla.firebase.app"** and run this URL in your browser!